# Un-reset Styles Defined by External Style-Sheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Say I have two style-sheets defined on my page:

- site.css:

  ```
  .modal {
      position: absolute;
      width: 200px;
      ...
  }

  ...
  ```
- reset.css:

  ```
  .reset * {
      position: static;
      width: auto;
      ...
  }
  ```

Unfortunately I have no control over the contents of the reset.css style-sheet. Now say the entire contents of the page are wrapped in a div block with a "reset" class applied. Deep within that div block I need to define a block of code which will ignore the styles defined by the this class.

As an example if I had a modal dialog with a class of "modal" applied I would need it to have absolute positioning with a width of 200px. I know I could re-define all the styles again but this would require me maintaining two versions of the same styles.

I've been racking my brains thinking how to do this and the only way I can think is via javascript (optionally using jQuery). If anyone knows how to do this or could share some sample code to get me going that would be great.

Comment: is overwiring the css from `site.css` with `!important` an option? if you have no control over `reset.css` then you will only have 1 version to maintain (in that you can't edit the other one)

Comment: @atmd: Nice idea but i'm afraid this isn't an option because I do wish for the .reset styles to work everywhere else apart from this one block of code.

Comment: yes but you'd only add the css you need to overwrite, not copy every selector, so only your .model code would exist in site.css with the !important flag

Comment: Thanks but the modal class was just an example. I don't really want to litter my style-sheet with a bunch of code to ignore the .reset class.

Comment: @atmd I ended up going for the !important idea. I didn't need to filter out the .reset styles as I initially feared. If you could add an answer with your comment then I will accept it. Thanks

Comment: done, have also offered a second arguably better solution to !important

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An option would be to override the styles in `reset.css` in your `site.css`.
You would only need to include styles you want to change as the rest will still take effect. There are two ways you could do this:

1. use `!important`

`.something{ color:red; } /* in reset.css */`

`.something{ color:blue !important; } /* in site.css */`

2. increase the specificity

`p{ color:red; } /* in reset.css */`

`div p{ color:blue; } /* in site.css */`

Using specificity is prob the best approach if possible, but using `!important` will also work. Here are the [MDN docs on specificity in css](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Answer (score 0):

You can give inline css dynamically using javascript. You first need to get the 'dialog element' into a variable say `myDialogElement`.Then you need to use the following code:

```
myDialogElement.style.position='absolute';
myDialogElement.style.width='200px';
```